# match everything besides one folder - regex

Tags: regex, eslint

I'm trying to exclude files form being watched besides folder `app` in `watchOptions` in ESLint.
My folder structure looks like:

```
├── assets
│   ├── assets
│   │   └── fonts
│   │       ├── FeatherIcons
│   │       ├── Icomoon
│   │       └── Montserrat
│   ├── images
│   ├── imagesNotOptimized
│   ├── js
│   │   ├── app
│   │   │   ├── api
│   │   │   │   ├── erpFlex
```

I would like to include all the files inside `app` but ignore all other files.

```
config.watchOptions = {
    poll: true,
    ignored: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets/js/*!(app)'),
    ]
};
```

I have tried the following regexes

1. assets/js/*(!app)
2. assets/js/(?!app)

Nothing seems to work. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you

**EDIT**
I have been able to match the string using the following regex: https://regex101.com/r/hs4lOt/1

but `path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets/js/(?!app).*')` is not working which makes this question not about regex but why `ignored` is not working in `watchOptions`

Comment: How about `assets/js/app/*.*`?

Comment: @CinCout I have updated the question. The regex I'm trying to achieve is the opposite of what you suggested. I'm trying to match all folders that **are** not `/app` folder

Comment: Can you confirm whether or not you are dealing with regex or glob?

Comment: @Soc Glob. I'm sorry for the mistake

Comment: From: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/164026, try: `assets/js/!(app)`